# Take custom category for custom posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a json file with data for custom taxonomy.
And then I need to filter that.. I do not have any problem with postmeta link and other fields. But i can't get the category into json. And then can't filtering that.

I know the answer must be very simple but i can't figure it out for 2 days.

```
function getItems( $meta_query ) {

$params = array(
    'post_type'         => 'property',
    'nopaging'          =>  true,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_query'        =>  array(),

$meta_query = array('meta_query'=>array(), 'relation' => 'AND');    

if (!empty($_POST['city']))
{
   $params['meta_query'][] =array(
          'key' => 'property_city',
          'value' => $_POST['city'],
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
}

if(!empty($_POST['parish']))
{
   $params['meta_query'][] = array(
          'key' => 'property_state',
          'value' => $_POST['parish'],
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}
//..................ETC..........................
```

What i have for category now:

```
//if (!empty($_POST['category']))
    /*{
    $params['meta_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pcategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_POST['category']->slug
                );
    }*/

    $itemsQuery = new WP_Query();
    $properties = $itemsQuery -> query($params);    

    // add property details
    foreach ($properties as $key => $property) {
        // options
        $property->optionsDir = get_post_meta($property->ID, 'property', true); 
        $city = get_post_meta($property->ID,  'property_city', true);
        $parish = get_post_meta($property->ID,  'property_state', true);    
        $link = get_permalink($property->ID);
        $category = get_the_terms($property->ID,'pcategory' );


        $properties[$key]->link = array(
        'link' => $link,
        );

        //postmeta
        $properties[$key]->postmeta = array(
         'city' => $city,
         'parish' => $parish,
         'region' => $region,
         'link' => $link,
         'category' => $category, 
        );

    }

    return $properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $category = get_the_terms($property->ID,'pcategory' );
```

Above code will return, all details like, term id, name, slug etc. information about that term, as an array object.

You need to extract the required details.

Also, "pcategory" is custom taxonomy.

Therefore, in below code,

```
$properties[$key]->postmeta = array(
         'city' => $city,
         'parish' => $parish,
         'region' => $region,
         'link' => $link,
         'category' => $category, 
        );
```

'category' will not be interpreted properly, as it is custom taxonomy and not default wordpress taxonomy.

If these parameters are sent to WP_Query(), you can mention 'tax_query' as below,

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pcategory',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'demo'
        )
```

Here, "demo" is example slug for custom taxonomy.

Even, single post can have multiple category associated with it. Therefore, you need to extract desired category details.

In 'tax_query' you can also specify, "term_id" or other details.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I did like that. I don't know what's wrong but the console of firebug don't stop to write ["Invalid taxonomy"] in json - category array.